# Struct Array in Bigquery with nested columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have two tables called source and base. The source table has a bunch of ids and all combination of weekly dates. The base table as ids, their tagged devices and the device start and end dates.

Example source table :

| id | com_date |
| --- | --- |
| acc_1 | 11/25/2022 |
| acc_1 | 11/18/2022 |
| acc_1 | 11/11/2022 |
| acc_2 | 11/25/2022 |
| acc_3 | 11/25/2022 |
| acc_3 | 11/25/2022 |

Example of base table :

| id | device_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| acc_1 | d1 | 11/24/2022 | 12/31/2999 |
| acc_1 | d2 | 11/19/2022 | 12/31/2999 |
| acc_1 | d3 | 11/12/2022 | 11/28/2022 |
| acc_2 | d4 | 11/20/2022 | 11/26/2022 |
| acc_3 | d5 | 11/17/2022 | 11/24/2022 |
| acc_3 | d6 | 11/10/2022 | 12/31/2999 |

I would like my final table to look something like this with nested columns -

[image]

Column count should be the count of distinct devices applicable for that com_date
and each com_date should lie between start_date and end_date

Comment: In *source table*,  *acc_3* has same date twice   .  one shouldn't be '11/28/2022' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider below query.

(I've tested it after changing last *com_date* in *source_table* to `11/18/2022`.)

```sql
SELECT s.id, s.com_date AS dates, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT device_id) count,
       ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(b.device_id, b.start_date AS to_date, b.end_date AS from_date)) d
  FROM source_table s JOIN base_table b 
    ON s.id = b.id 
   AND PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', com_date) BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', start_date) AND PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', end_date)
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

[image]